# Renaming bunch of files with their parent folder name on OS X

Tags: macos, terminal, filenames, batch-rename, suffix

I have files as follows: (Some files are located inside nested folders)

```
/1/asd.m
/3/asd.m
/4/2/asd.m
```

I want to rename .m files with a suffix of their parent folder name. The result should be like this:

```
/1/asd1.m
/3/asd3.m
/4/2/asd2.m
```

How can I do this on Mac terminal?

Answer (score 2):

Simplier and more universal way that takes dirnames with spaces into consideration:

```
find . -name '*.mp3' -exec bash -xc 'dn=$(dirname "{}"); fn=$(basename "{}"); mv -v "{}" "$dn/$dn-$fn" ' \;
```

Result (verbosity via `bash -x`):

```
++ dirname './80 дней вокруг света/56.mp3'
+ dn='./80 дней вокруг света'
++ basename './80 дней вокруг света/56.mp3'
+ fn=56.mp3
+ mv -v './80 дней вокруг света/56.mp3' './80 дней вокруг света/./80 дней вокруг света-56.mp3'
./80 дней вокруг света/56.mp3 -> ./80 дней вокруг света/./80 дней вокруг света-56.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the folder that contains your files is `rename_folder`:

```
rename_folder/1/asd.m
rename_folder/3/asd.m
rename_folder/4/2/asd.m
```

You can rename those files with this command:

```
find rename_folder -type f -name "*.m" -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; fn="${x##*/}"; dn="$(dirname $x)"; mv "$x" "${dn}/${fn%%.*}${dn##*/}.${fn#*.}"' \;
```

Results should be:

```
rename_folder/1/asd1.m
rename_folder/3/asd3.m
rename_folder/4/2/asd2.m
```

Comment: I used your code but had a problem when there is a space in the path or file name. dirname was not working properly. I just added a "'s in (dirname "$x") I used the following modified code:
find rename_folder -type f -name "*.m" -exec sh -c 'x="{}"; fn="${x##*/}"; dn="$(dirname "$x")"; mv "$x" "${dn}/${fn%%.*}${dn##*/}.${fn#*.}"' \;